# Get Zendesk attachment as base64 instead auto download

Tags: salesforce, attachment, apex, zendesk

I need to get attachment file from zendesk in base64 format.

I try to do this but it's not worked for me:

`HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://-----.zendesk.com/attachments/token/TOKEN/?name=stvm+%2810%29.pdf');
req.setMethod('GET');

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

**Blob body= res.getBodyAsBlob()**;`

But the body value it's working as i need.

The response it's something like that:

`<html><body>You are being <a href="https://xxx.zdusercontent.com/attachment/000001/sdlfkashdf98709udfah?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaX46SgYrFzTEpYqUIzpQeNnl5BMBNoRnUOsgQj389Ei7nNcGOcfGYaavlqLL2qaIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..U8oX8QnYBM1lZMb6rhQGRA.NC3Z9kHC9ZE6HhygIHHan6xWYvoPqziVx76CZ6vcNYHBuAjV-LmBclVJYumKWKXA_PDhXX27z977XKYrLJZSc85a6lJTEqd-V2mP7U6O6r0_6E9hO8CWaA1dyxYYWw8kUsgMFUaPr0wCupxm3NbDzT03ZwO6EBJj79x4UZdauiXfEUrSwdl1pPahlQE2VfFo8DprgX9GQHzRFm5lwMrhA3crogo8Ox`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution for my problem.

In salesforce apex code I got the URL response by `substring` method and I used `Pagereferece` to open the URL, see below:

```
String exampleMyResponse= '<html><body>You are being <a href="https://xxx.zdusercontent.com/attachment/000001/sdlfkashdf98709udfah?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaX46SgYrFzTEpYqUIzpQeNnl5BMBNoRnUOsgQj389Ei7nNcGOcfGYaavlqLL2qaIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..U8oX8QnYBM1lZMb6rhQGRA.NC3Z9kHC9ZE6HhygIHHan6xWYvoPqziVx76CZ6vcNYHBuAjV-LmBclVJYumKWKXA_PDhXX27z977XKYrLJZSc85a6lJTEqd-V2mP7U6O6r0_6E9hO8CWaA1dyxYYWw8kUsgMFUaPr0wCupxm3NbDzT03ZwO6EBJj79x4UZdauiXfEUrSwdl1pPahlQE2VfFo8DprgX9GQHzRFm5lwMrhA3crogo8Ox';
```

```
//You need to authorize your domain "https://xxx.zdusercontent.com" in remote site
Pagereference pg = new Pagereference(exampleMyResponse.substringAfter('href="')); 
Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF();
    
Attachment att = new Attachment(Name = 'stvm_4', Body = b, ContentType = 'application/pdf', ParentId='Sobject_Id');
insert att;
```